In a real TVS, does convergence of a net of reals times a nonzero vector imply convergence of the real net?
I am having trouble proving $r_i x \longrightarrow y$  with $i\in I$ in a topological vector space $B$, where $x\neq 0$, implies $r_i$ converges in $\mathbb R$. I am not even sure it is true.
If the mapping $s\mapsto y-sx$ is open the proof might look like this. Take an open nhd $U$ of $0$ in $\mathbb R$ then $V := \{y-sx\mid s\in U\}$ is an open nhd of $y$ in $B$ (by open map?) so $r_i x$ is eventually in $V$ so $r_i x - r_j x$ is eventually in $V-y$,  which is an open nhd of $0$ in $B$, so $r_i - r_j$ is eventually in $U$ (because?). Therefore, the net is Cauchy in $\mathbb R$ and so converges.
I have highlighted the gaps in the proof with ? Can someone advise whether the convergence claim is true, and if so, what is the proof, is the above proof on the right track?
In a normed vector space the result holds. We would have
$|r_i - r_j|\|x\|=\|(r_i - r_j)x\|=\|r_i x - r_j x\|\le\|(r_i x-y)-(r_j x-y)\|\longrightarrow0$ because  $r_i x \longrightarrow y$  so since  $\|x\|\neq 0$  because $x\neq 0$, we get $|r_i - r_j|\longrightarrow 0$, that is $r_i$ is Cauchy and so converges.

Your argument isn't very useful, because $s\mapsto y-sx$ is not open unless $\dim V\leq 1$.  Here's an argument you can make instead.  First, note that a net $(r_i)$ converges to $r$ iff every subnet of $(r_i)$ has a subsubnet that converges to $r$.  If $(r_i)$ is eventually bounded, then every subnet has a convergent subsubnet, so every subnet of $(r_ix)$ has a subsubnet that converges to some element of the form $rx$ where the subnet converges to $r$.  All of these $rx$'s must be equal to $y$, which implies all the $r$'s must be the same, so the entire net $(r_i)$ must converge to $r$.
Thus we may assume $(r_i)$ is not eventually bounded. Now we may assume WLOG that $ry\neq x$ for $|r|\leq 1$ (since there is at most one $r$ such that $ry=x$ and we can rescale $x$ to make this $r$ outside of $[-1,1]$).  Note that the image $K$ of the map $f:[-1,1]\to V$ given by $f(r)=ry-x$ is compact and does not contain $0$, so its complement is an open neighborhood $U$ of $0$.  By continuity of scalar multiplication at $(0,0)$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ and an open neighborhood $U'$ of $0$ such that $cv\in U$ for all $|c|<\epsilon$ and $v\in U'$.  Now $(y-r_ix)$ is eventually in $U'$, and since $(r_i)$ is not eventually bounded, we can pass to a subnet and assume that $|r_i|>1/\epsilon$ and also that $|r_i|>1$ for all $i$.  For $c=1/r_i$, we then have $c(y-r_ix)=cy-x\in U$.  But since $|c|<1$, $cy-x\in K$, and this is a contradiction.

Thanks so much Eric, I had almost given up on this one getting an answer.
